# Finding objects that are within a time range of each other

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, object, time

I am using an external API to fetch a list of events happening between two dates. I have then used `array.reduce` to group the events happening on the same day into one array.

```
const time = events && events.reduce((acc, item) => {
    if (!acc[item.fixture.date.split('T')[1]]) {
      acc[item.fixture.date.split('T')[1]] = [];
    }

    acc[item.fixture.date.split('T')[1]].push(item);
    return acc;
  }, {})
```

They are labelled by the time in which the event occurs. If I console.log `time` then you can see in the image below how the data is returned for one day.

[Example of returned data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AilOH.png)

I am trying to work out how to loop through these objects and find the ones that are within 30 minutes of each other. For example: It would find `16:05:00+01:00` and `16:30:00+01:00` and place these into a new array called `Interval` together.

What would be the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: First - have you created a function to compare two dates / times to see if they are within 30 minutes of each other? I'm actually a little confused about what data structure you're working with so no second yet.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I'm sorry, my Javascript knowledge is fairly limited. I've edited my question above to hopefully provide some more detail about what I'm working with. I can create a function to compare two values but I'm unsure how best to create a function that compares multiple values. Thanks!

Comment: Vaguely what I was thinking, is that if the dates you want to loop through are ordered then you need only use your function to compare each event to the previous one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const datesInRange = (date1, date2, range) => //range = difference in minutes
  (date1 - date2) / 1000 / 60 <= range 
  ? true : false
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there a way to incorporate this calculation into the `array.reduce` I'm using above? It's currently set up to push objects with matching values into a new array together so I'm wondering whether it might be possible to also push any objects that are 30 minutes apart into an array together? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah you could use it like this >>> if ( datesInRange(firstDate, secondDate, 30) ) ) //add it to the array